# 3.5mm Headphone and Mic --> 3.5mm Headphone and 3.5mm Mic

Tags: headphones, av-cable

I am looking for a way to take the plug from an ear bud and mic set (e.g. the VModa Vibe Duo) and split it into separate headphone and mic 3.5mm plugs so that I can plug them into my computer.

Has anyone seen such a splitter?

The reason why I ask is that I work from home, and long conference calls with a big set of over-the-hear headphones can get tiring. I'd therefore like to try with a nice ear bud/mic set and see if that is more comfortable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this [2.5mm split adapter](http://chatcable.com/blog/?page_id=3&category=2&product_id=1) and then a [2.5mm to 3.5mm adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002VL7Z4K).
Not optimal but couldn't find a 3.5mm split adapter to mic and headphone.

Another option is of course to build one yourself, but I guess that wasn't what you had in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That is what I am looking for and will work with the adapter. I'll wait a little while to see if somebody comes up with a 3.5mm version. If not, I'll give you the checkmark :)

Comment: Great, hope you can get hold of them and it works as intended!

Answer (score 0):

At many electronics stores you can have custom cables made. If you're somewhat nifty at soldering, you could probably even get the separate connectors and make one yourself. You'd not only have a single cable, but one at the length you want.

I'm afraid I can't give any recommendations as I live in the Netherlands.

Comment: I hadn't thought about trying to get an electronics store to custom make the cable for me. I'm more looking for an off the shelf solution (making it at home would be fun, but it's yet another project ;). Thanks for the suggestion!